# Why are there so many confirmations?

Tags: confirmations

A friend sent me Bitcoin to my blockchain wallet. It shows the amount as part of my balance. However, it says there are 108 confirmations and the number of confirmations keeps going up. Why is this happening? Can I spend this Bitcoin while confirmations are continuing?

Comment: You really should wait until the first transaction confirms before spending any of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of confirmations indicates under how many blocks your transaction is buried. The more the confirmations, the more your transaction is secure from double-spending attacks. So the confirmations will continue growing forever - this is normal behavior.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. What is throwing me off is that my other transaction is not showing the confirmation box. Is that because I spent a piece of it?